# How to Group and Sum items using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have data in the following format which I have in a C# List object :

```
Id  Value
1   5
2   3
3   -2
1   27
2   0
3   1
1   -4
```

And I would like to create a 3 dimensional List from this data in the following format :

```
Id  Count  TotalValue
1   3      28
2   2      3
3   2      -1
```

I am not sure of the syntax to use in LINQ to do this, can anybody help?

Comment: Your second list isn't three dimensional, it's 2 dimensional with (n) values down and 3 values across.   [Image of a 3 dimensional table](https://static.javatpoint.com/tutorial/datawarehouse/images/data-warehouse-what-is-multi-dimensional-data-model4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this

```cs
var result = data.GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Id = group.Key,
        Count = group.Count(),
        TotalValue = group.Sum(item => item.Value)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: oops sorry this is the same as giorgi's answer

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to use the [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0)
Then you'll want to create a new object that takes each group and calculates ([Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-7.0) and [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-7.0)) the values to want from them:

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w9mgdG)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var source = new List<(int Id, int Value)>
        {
            (1, 5),
            (2, 3),
            (3, -2),
            (1, 27),
            (2, 0),
            (3, 1),
            (1, -4),
        };
        
        var computed = source
         .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
         .Select(x => new {Id = x.Key, Count = x.Count(), TotalValue = x.Sum(s => s.Value)})
         .ToList();
        
        foreach(var value in computed)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{value.Id} {value.Count} {value.TotalValue}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 1 3 28
>
> 2 2 3
>
> 3 2 -1

Answer (score -1):

Let me use a tuple  for an object

```
var x = new List<(int Id, int Value)>();
            
var y = x.GroupBy(_ => _.Id).Select(_ => new { Id = _.Key, Count = _.Count(), TotalValue = _.Sum(i => i.Value) });
```